# Is there FOR ... IN ... loop in Java similar to Python one?

Tags: java

I can iterate in array using Pythons for loops as

```
arr = []
for e in arr:
    do smth. with each element
```

Does java has similar loop? If I will split the string in Java like this:

```
temp = str.split(delimiter);
```

Will I have array which can be looped with "for ... in..." similar statement?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? read any help perhaps ? 2 seconds in my favourite search engine finds this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the `foreach` "statement":

```
for (final E element: array) {
    // do whatever with element
}
```

It works with arrays and all kinds of Collections as well (Sets, Lists, Maps), and in general for any class `X` which implements `Iterable<X>`, ie, `Iterable` of itself (which means you can write a class to use in a foreach statement, which is nice).

So, you could write directly:

```
for (final String s: str.split(delimiter)) {
    // work with s
}
```

as `.split()` returns an array, which is directly useable with a foreach statement. That is, if you don't need another variable to hold the array index for whatever reason.

Comment: "Should" is too strong -- but anyway, here, the `final` will avoid that you accidentally reuse s in the loop (if you try, this will be a compile error).

Comment: `final` prevents you from re-assigning to the variable inside of the loop. That would be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (String part: str.split(delimiter)){
  // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop is there in java.

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/ForLoop.shtml

In java 1.5, using enhanced for loop.

```
for (String str : temp) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```